# Emacs detect terminal Unicode coverage

Tags: unicode

I `diminish` my minor modes into single Unicode characters to save space. However, this obviously breaks down in a Linux TTY for instance. How can I detect if the current display method supports Unicode (or better yet, can display a specific character)?

Note: Simply detecting a graphical frame is not enough, as many graphical terminal emulators support Unicode, but emacs does not run in a graphical frame.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with your last sentence, but `display-graphic-p` always returns `nil` when Emacs is running in a terminal, whether it's “graphical” or not.

Comment: @lunaryorn Exactly. `display-graphic-p` being `nil` is not strong enough to guarantee a lack of Unicode.

Comment: But it being non-nil almost guarantees unicode support.

Comment: ... which is why I'm asking about detecting _terminal_ Unicode coverage.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood your question.  I don't think that's possible, though:  On TTY frames, Emacs has no influence whatsoever on the font selection, and thus on unicode support, and it can't detect which fonts the terminal emulator uses.

Comment: If it were enough to detect whether Emacs is running in a textual terminal, but not running in the Linux TTY (which can only display 256 different glyphs and should set TERM appropriately), that could be used as indicator instead.

Comment: PythonNut Is there any other terminal like Linux TTY on WINDOWS whose support for unicode is limited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot.

If Emacs is speaking to a terminal, it only knows which coding system is spoken by the terminal.  If the coding system is a locale-specific one (say, ISO 8859-1 or Shift-JIS), then it is a good bet that the terminal supports most or all of the characters in the coding system.  If the coding system is Unicode-based, then there is no way to know which particular subset of Unicode the terminal is able to display.

On a Unicode terminal, `char-displayable-p` answers `unicode` for all Unicode characters.

Answer (score -1):

> How can I detect if the current display method supports Unicode (or better yet, can display a specific character)?

You can detect if emacs can display a specific character with the [`char-displayable-p`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/char-displayable-p) function.

```
(char-displayable-p ?☺)
```

You can insert such unicode chars with `C-x 8`, or use their hex code preceded by a `\x`.

Comment: This returns "unicode" in both a linux TTY that doesn't support Unicode, and a GNOME terminal that does. I don't think it actually does any display detection.

Comment: @PythonNut I guess it works with font detection. Sorry it didn't help.